# MUI textfield with min-max inputProps not updating when using value from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am using a mui textfield and it works fine when I use it without hooking it upto the state but once I hook it to the state, the

```
    <TextField
      size="small"
      type="number"
      inputProps={{ min: 0, max: 999 }}
    />
```

This is the default one that was working like a charm but the moment I hook it upto the state, it starts to break. After tweaking it around I got it to display the value and not overlap the placeholder but now I can't seem to be able to handle the value change.

```
    <TextField
      size="small"
      type="number"
      label="px"
      value={shapeHeight}
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
      inputProps={{ min: 0, max: 999 }}
      onChange={(e) => { console.warn(e.target.value)}}
    />
```

Was just trying to check if onChange works but all it returns is 1 over and over again.
Now I could make do it that and on every click just increment the value once but onChange only works when clicking the up arrow and not the down arrow.

Next I tried to use onClick and it works on both up and down arrow click but I have no way to differentiate between the two different clicks.

Comment: Do you change `shapeHeight` state on `onChange`? The snippet only prints the new value, and does not change the state.

Comment: @Bar I got it working. Thank you for the answer bdw.

Method -   const setRectangleHeight = (event) => {
    dispatch(action to update state in redux store)
  }
JSX- 
            <TextField
              size="small"
              type="number"
              value={height}
              inputProps={{ min: 0 }}
              onChange={setRectangleHeight}
            />
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-hawking-pz8f5s?file=/src/App.tsx:967-982